# Winforms buttons stuck on Enabled = false WS_Disabled?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, winapi

In our 'big' Winforms .Net application a couple of buttons are stuck in a strange state.

After setting the container panel to Enabled = False and setting the button to Enabled = True and then setting the panel to Enabled = True the button doesn't seem to react to any Mouse events anymore. It won't paint itself correctly and the WS_Disabled state is still set for the button.

The control's are not reacting to mouse overs or button clicks but are drawn like active button's should. (not greyed out). Using tab I can actually focus the control's and they do paint themself selected or hovered if I tab through them when the mouse is over the buttons.

Some scrollbars seem stuck too, but the Grid they are hosting is still editable.

Is there any easy way to debug how and why some button's are stuck? Using Spy++ i've seen they have WS_Disabled set as a style, but I have no clue how that can happen.

We're using DevExpress components with version 12.2. But this also occured on previous versions.

Comment: WinForms is for .NET applications. Are you sure WinForms is involved, and not just windows?

Comment: Afaik Winforms for .Net is build on the functionality supplied by windows. .Net winforms is just a fancy .Net view of the Win32 objects.

Comment: I know, nothing else in your question suggested .NET, hence asking for clarification.

Comment: You toggle the Enabled state and get WS_DISABLED style, what else do you expect?

Comment: That if I retoggle the Enabled state that it should work again.